# problem in Webscraping by Python/ Python prints classes first in CSV then prints the information

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I want to get info from the website by Web scraping with python(I learn it now), but it prints classes (which I got the info from) first in CSV then prints the information which I want. I saw the Youtube video many times, and I wrote the same code but it doesn't happen like the problem which I got. Is there anyone kan HELP me?

This is an image link for CSV to show you how It looks when I click on RUN
[image]

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

Job_titles = []
Company_names = []
Location_names = []
Job_skills = []
Links = []
result = requests.get("https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?q=python&a=hpb")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
Job_titles = soup.find_all('h2', {"class":"css-m604qf"})
Company_names = soup.find_all('a', {"class":"css-17s97q8"})
Location_names = soup.find_all('span', {"class":"css-5wys0k"})
Job_skills = soup.find_all("div", {'class':"css-y4udm8"})

for i in range(len(Company_names)):
    Job_titles.append(Job_titles[i].text)
    Company_names.append(Company_names[i].text)
    Location_names.append(Location_names[i].text)
    Job_skills.append(Job_skills[i].text)

file_list = [Job_titles, Company_names, Location_names, Job_skills,]
exported = zip_longest(*file_list)
with open("C:/Users/Saleh saleh/Documents/jobtest.csv", "w") as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow(["Job titles", "Company names", "Location", "Skills", "Links"])
    wr.writerows(exported)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get information from the site, you can use following example:

```py
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?q=python&a=hpb"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

with open("data.csv", "w") as f_in:
    writer = csv.writer(f_in)
    writer.writerow(
        ["Job titles", "Company names", "Location", "Skills", "Links"]
    )

    for title in soup.select("h2 > a"):
        company_name = title.find_next("a")
        location = company_name.find_next("span")
        info = location.find_next("div", {"class": None})

        writer.writerow(
            [
                title.text,
                company_name.text,
                location.text,
                ",".join(
                    a.text.replace("·", "").strip() for a in info.select("a")
                ),
                title["href"],
            ]
        )
```

Creates `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, but can you explain shortly what you did because I didn't understand exactly what your cod means hahaha "I'm a beginner". Thank you again.